# The first div block has a weird style that I am unable to remove

Tags: html, css

There is a weird spacing between the elements of the original div that is coded in the html but i am unable to remove it no matter what.

[image]

```
<body>
  <form class='myform'>
    <div class='form-block'>
      <span class='line'>1</span>
      <button class='new-line'>New Line</button>
      <button class='new-nested'>New Nested Line</button>
      <input class='input' type='text' placeholder='Enter Value...'>
      <button class='new-input'>Add input</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Please find the fiddle here:

```js
function createNode() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'form-block');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.setAttribute('class', 'line');
    var b1 = document.createElement('button');
    b1.setAttribute('class', 'new-line');
    b1.textContent = 'New Line';
    var b2 = document.createElement('button');
    b2.setAttribute('class', 'new-nested');
    b2.textContent = 'New Nested Line';
    var b3 = document.createElement('button');
    b3.setAttribute('class', 'new-input');
    b3.textContent = 'Add input';
    var ip = document.createElement('input');
    ip.setAttribute('class', 'input');
    ip.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    ip.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter Value...');
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", span.outerHTML);
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", b1.outerHTML);
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", b2.outerHTML);
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ip.outerHTML);
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", b3.outerHTML);

    var d2 = document.getElementsByClassName("form-block")[0];
    return div;
};

function newLine() {
    console.log("new line");
    var toBeAdded = createNode();
    var theDivParent = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    var previousLast;
    var had = theDivParent.lastChild.hasChildNodes();
    if (had) {
        previousLast = theDivParent.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("line")[0].innerText.split(".");
        var len = previousLast.length;
        var num = parseInt(previousLast[len - 1]);
        num++;
        previousLast[len - 1] = num;
    }
    theDivParent.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", toBeAdded.outerHTML);
    var len = theDivParent.getElementsByClassName("form-block").length;
    if (!had) {
        theDivParent.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("line")[0].innerText = 2;
    } else {
        theDivParent.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("line")[0].innerText = previousLast.join(".");
    }
    theDivParent.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("new-line")[0].onclick = newLine;
    theDivParent.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("new-input")[0].onclick = newInput;
    theDivParent.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("new-nested")[0].onclick = newNested;
    return false;
};

function newNested() {
    console.log("new line");
    var toBeAdded = createNode();
    var theDiv = this.parentElement;
    theDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", toBeAdded.outerHTML);
    var len = theDiv.getElementsByClassName("form-block").length;
    theDiv.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("line")[0].innerText = theDiv.getElementsByClassName("line")[0].innerText + "." + len;
    theDiv.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("new-line")[0].onclick = newLine;
    theDiv.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("new-input")[0].onclick = newInput;
    theDiv.lastChild.getElementsByClassName("new-nested")[0].onclick = newNested;
    return false;
};

function newInput() {
    console.log("new input");
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
    this.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", elem[0].outerHTML);
    return false;
};

document.getElementsByClassName("new-input")[0].onclick = newInput;

document.getElementsByClassName("new-line")[0].onclick = newLine;

document.getElementsByClassName("new-nested")[0].onclick = newNested;

document.getElementsByClassName("myform")[0].onsubmit = function () {
    return false;
}
```

```css
div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: green;
}

button {}

input {}

span {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form class='myform'>
        <div class='form-block'>
            <span class='line'>1</span>
            <button class='new-line'>New Line</button>
            <button class='new-nested'>New Nested Line</button>
            <input class='input' type='text' placeholder='Enter Value...'>
            <button class='new-input'>Add input</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Pls share your `HTML` and `CSS` code.

Comment: @chaitz9 Please find the fiddle attached, was not able to add the code because it was asking to insert text into it and wont let me submit

Comment: If you're talking about only the *first* line, that's because the HTML that you've shown has text nodes (white space) between each element. Remove that white space and the "weird" spacing disappears: http://jsfiddle.net/q2enzjw9/1/

Comment: Just put the html on the same line: http://jsfiddle.net/q2enzjw9/3/

Comment: Mark the question as done, if this solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this arcticle: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
The HTML makes spaces between inline-block elements. When you press `CTRL + A` you can see there's a single space. 
To fight this space you can do the following (mentioned in the arcticle aswell):

Open the tag on the previous line:

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li>
>    one</li><li>
>    two</li><li>
>    three</li>
> </ul>
> ```

Add the last closing brackets on the new line:

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li>one</li
>   ><li>two</li
>   ><li>three</li>
> </ul>
> ```

Or put comments, starting from the previous line to the following line.

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li>one</li><!--
>   --><li>two</li><!--
>   --><li>three</li>
> </ul>
> ```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Dont forget to upvote, I need these points ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use float css property to remove the whitespace between elements.

```
<body>
<form class='myform'>
<div class='form-block'>
  <span class='line floated'>1</span>
  <button class='new-line floated'>New Line</button>
  <button class='new-nested floated'>New Nested Line</button>
  <input class='input floated' type='text' placeholder='Enter Value...'>
  <button class='new-input floated'>Add input</button>
</div>
```

```
.floated {
   float:left;
}
```

Updated JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsachin/LL7n983c/1/

Answer (score 0):

add this style to the css file:

```
button { float: left; }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2enzjw9/6/)

Answer (score -1):

[here is update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2enzjw9/4/)

I have removed the space between tags like

```
<span class='line'>1</span><button class='new-line'>New Line</button><button class='new-nested'>New Nested Line</button><input class='input' type='text' placeholder='Enter Value...'><button class='new-input'>Add input</button>
```